# Using file_get_contents in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm very new to CodeIgniter, and I am finding it difficult to get into. I am currently trying to use the following API (http://pokeapi.co) inside my site so that I can bring back the JSON file and manipulate it. As far as I can see, I should be having the user searching for a Pokemon in the view, passing the search back to the model and using file_get_contents to get the JSON file and then pass it back to the view for manipulation.

Is this correct? How would I go about doing that?

My CodeIgniter code so far is not at all functional, but I can do this without CodeIgniter like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Pokedex!</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <form name="search" action="api_test.php" method="POST">
        <label>Please search for a Pokemon</label>
        <input type="search" name="pokemon" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And;

```
<?php

$pokemon = strtolower($_POST['pokemon']);
$siteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" . $pokemon . "/";
$data = file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI);

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var obj = <?php echo $data; ?>;     

        document.write("<p>Name: " + obj.name + "</p>");
        document.write("<p>Pokedex Number: " + obj.national_id + "</p>");               
        document.write("<p>Height: " + obj.height + "</p>");
        document.write("<p>Weight: " + obj.weight + "</p>");            
    </script>
</body>
```

So my quesiton really is - how do I convert this to work with CodeIgniter? Could I also use AJAX to avoid a page refresh?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the CI you need to create a Controller Method, this method , you put your code as:

```
public function catchPokemon($pokemon)
{
    $pokemon = strtolower($pokemon);
    $siteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" . $pokemon . "/";
    $data = file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI);

    $this->load->view('catches', json_decode($data));
}
```

Then you need to create a view ( catches.php ) to analyze data like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Name: <strong><?php echo $name; ?></strong></p>
    <p>Pokedex Number: <strong><?php echo $national_id; ?></strong></p>
    <p>Height: <strong><?php echo $height; ?></strong></p>
    <p>Weight: <strong><?php echo $weight; ?></strong></p>
</body>
```

Now , you can call the controller method via ajax request with jQuery.

i.e.:

Controller

```
class Pokemon extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    /**
     * Calls with http://yourhost/Pokemon/catchPokemon/PokemonName
     */
    public function catchPokemon($pokemon)
    {
        $pokemon = strtolower($pokemon);
        $siteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" . $pokemon . "/";
        $data = file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI);

        $this->load->view('catches', json_decode($data));
    }
}
```

View index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Pokedex!</title>
    ......Scripts and styles references......
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var finish = function(data){
                $('#poke').html(data);
            };

            $('#search').submit(function(){
                $.get("http://yourhost/Pokemon/catchPokemon/" +
                        $('#pokemon').val(), finish);

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form id="search">
        <label>Please search for a Pokémon</label>
        <input type="search" name="pokemon" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="poke"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

View catches.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Name: <strong><?php echo $name; ?></strong></p>
    <p>Pokedex Number: <strong><?php echo $national_id; ?></strong></p>
    <p>Height: <strong><?php echo $height; ?></strong></p>
    <p>Weight: <strong><?php echo $weight; ?></strong></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! Just to confirm, where you say "yourhost/Pokemon/catchPokemon", I need to be referencing my Contoller and function there?

Comment: No, they are different, the second is in response to the comment made earlier.

Comment: You cannot just put answers like chat. Edit your first answer and delete one of them.

Comment: Yep! Reference there.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Smith, I'll arrange it.

Comment: I feel like I am really close to this working, but at the moment when I search, nothing is bought back, no error messages or anything.

Comment: Yeah, I really dont know what is going wrong now. Ignoring the fact that some of my file names are different from yours (which I beleive I have allowed for in the files), my code matches yours. Ma I meant to be using my own Javascript from the original code to manipulate the JSON file, or is that taken care of in the '$name' variables etc?

Comment: I got it working. I had to change the AJAX code and move away from using a HTML5 form to get it to work though. Should I post that code in this chat, or in an new answer?

Comment: ...what? I don't speak whatever that language is, sorry.

Comment: put your code in fiddle jsfiddle.net - sorry for the language ;)